# Plesk Cronjob Command - Reached memory_limit

Tags: cron, cron-task

I try to implement a cronjob that does a huge task.
Now I tried the following in Plesk:

Added a task with this command:

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php -f '/var/www/vhosts/mydomain/wp-content/plugins/importer/cron/cron.php' 'sopa2930kas96' -d max_execution_time=0 memory_limit=2048M
```

I also tried this one:

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php -f '/var/www/vhosts/mydomain/wp-content/plugins/importer/cron/cron.php' 'sopa2930kas96' -d max_execution_time=0 -d memory_limit=2048M
```

Unfortunately I'm still getting the error that I reached the memory_limit of about 134 000 bytes.

Is this the wrong way how to increase the memory_limit?

Is there a way to ignore the memory_limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I simply had the wrong order in my command.
This is the working command line:

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php -d max_execution_time=0 -d memory_limit=2048M -f '/var/www/vhosts/mydomain/wp-content/plugins/importer/cron/cron.php' 'sopa2930kas96'
```